# Splitting long lines in sssd.conf

Tags: linux, ldap, sles, sssd

I have an MS-AD domain joined SLES server, using sssd to control access.
Is there a way to break long lines in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file for readability purposes?

From this:

```
ldap_group_search_base = ou=groups_ou_1,dc=company,dc=com???ou=groups_ou_2,dc=company,dc=com???ou=groups_ou_3,dc=company,dc=com???ou=groups_ou_4,dc=company,dc=com??
```

To this:

```
ldap_group_search_base = ou=groups_ou_1,dc=company,dc=com \
                      ???ou=groups_ou_2,dc=company,dc=com \
                      ???ou=groups_ou_3,dc=company,dc=com \
                      ???ou=groups_ou_4,dc=company,dc=com??
```

*Note*, if I restart sssd service after introducing above line breaks, there are no complains in the journal but `ls -l` on a directory with domain group membership does not resolve, so that clearly does not work.

OS: `SLES 15.4` 
sssd version: `2.5.2-150400.4.11.1`

Comment: Nope, cannot be done, nor can you set vars within it and reference them. It has been asked for, but it just does not support it. It's a royal pain in the wotzit.

Comment: Thanks @Bib. That's unfortunate